# How can I do multipart requests mith Mojo::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'd like to perform a multipart file upload to Google Drive as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/multipart-upload) using a Mojo::UserAgent. I currently do it like this:

```
my $url = Mojo::URL->new('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files');
$url->query({ fields => 'id,parents', 
              ocr => 'true', 
              ocrLanguage => 'de', 
              uploadType => 'multipart' });


my $tx = $ua->post($url,
                   json => { parents => [ '0ByFk4UawESNUX1Bwak1Ka1lwVE0' ] },
                   {
                       'Content-Type' => 'multipart/related',
                       'parents' => [ '0ByFk4UawESNUX1Bwak1Ka1lwVE0' ]
                   },
                   $content );
```

but it doesn't work.

I've managed authorization OK (omitted here) and simple file upload works fine. I just can't seem to do the multipart.

I've tried to make sense of the docs [here](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Content/MultiPart) - but to no avail, in the sense that the file gets uploaded OK, but the JSON part gets ignored, and the file gets uploaded in the root folder.

Comment: Does it give any error messages? What's the response?

Comment: Could you also include a text dump of the request? I guess https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent#DEBUGGING can give you that.

Comment: I was asking for the request. You need to compare your request to the example given in the documentation.

Comment: Do you still need help with this? I'm just starting to look at it.

Comment: @borodin - I've figured out _something_ by creating `Mojo::Content::Single` objects, adding `Mojo::Asset::Memory` and headers, and then putting them all in a `Mojo::Content::MultiPart` object. Looks ugly to me - or is it the only way?