# How to POST a multipart/related message to a HTTP server?

Tags: perl, http, post, multipart

How to POST a `multipart/related` message of two parts to a HTTP(S) server?

I need this for https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload

We use Perl 5.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Please add a [mcve] to your question

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cpan+HTTP+POST+multipart

Comment: @Quentin Your link points to `multipart/form-data` while I need `multipart/related`.

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. Do you have the multipart/related body already and just want to know how to post it or do you ask how to construct such a body in the first place?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I need to perform a multipart upload as in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload (I need to construct the POST request body)

Comment: @porton: if you have an understanding of MIME you can write it by hand and there is even an example in the documentation you reference. And it links to the standard which describes what to do. Or you could use libraries like MIME::Tools to construct it. There is nothing special with multipart/related compared to multipart/mixed or other multipart/..

Comment: There was a question about this in relation to the Mojo user agent about a week or two ago. They had trouble with the metadata. I can't find it from my phone though..

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: This is something that is missing from all the HTTP client modules that I know. It would really help if there were some facility to calculate stuff like an appropriate separator and the `Content-length` header. The writer should have to provide only the data for the parts.

Comment: @simbabque: You mean [*How can I do multipart requests mith Mojo::UserAgent?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46521633/622310) but it's not very useful.

Comment: @Borodin I think I've got some tuits laying around here. Did you just volunteer for some hacktoberfest fun? :-)

Comment: @simbabque: I would be happy to add to `Mojolicious` or `LWP`, but my concern is the amount of time it would take to understand how best to do it in keeping with the existing design philosophy. There's some mysterious stuff in both of those suites.

Comment: @simbabque: The `Mojolicious` GitHub repository has a new version of `Mojo::UserAgent::Transactor` has a new transactor `multipart` to go with `form` and `json`, and I think that's going to be the best solution when it's finally pushed to CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

Some demonstration of how to send a multipart/related body to some site. I don't know if this sends exactly the data required by the Google API, but it should give you the idea. It is still recommended that you get basic understanding of MIME, especially constructions of multipart messages in MIME (where multipart/related is just one example) and about Content-Transfer-Encoding. The [Wikipedia entry to MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) might be a good start for this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP;
use MIME::Base64 'encode_base64';
use HTTP::Request;

# Create the parts, each consisting of MIME-Header and body.
my $part1 =
    "Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n".
    "some json here\r\n";
my $part2 =
    "Content-type: image/gif\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n".
    encode_base64("...image data here...");

# Combine the parts to a single multipart, using the boundary defined later
# in the Content-Type.
my $body =
    "--some-boundary\r\n".     # start of 1st part
    $part1.
    "--some-boundary\r\n".     # start of 2nd part
    $part2.
    "--some-boundary--\r\n";   # end boundary

# Create the request. The Content-type is multiplart/related and defines
# the boundary used to separate the parts.
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(
    POST => 'http://example.com/api/postit',
    [
        'Content-length' => length($body),
        'Content-type'   => 'multipart/related; boundary="some-boundary"',
    ],
    $body
);
LWP::UserAgent->new->request($req);
```

Comment: It is better to use `MIME::Tools` and `MIME::Entity`, as somebody mentioned

Comment: @porton: It was actually me who suggested this. In a way it would be more nice to hide some details of MIME and I would recommend to do it for production code. But on the other side with this code doing the construction of the multipart message itself one can better see how such multipart works and can relate it better to the example given in the API documentation which shows the raw MIME message.